# mysqldump with single tables much slower than with --all-databases

Tags: performance, backup, mysql, database-performance

I use two different ways to backup my mysql database. mysqldump with  --all-databases  is much faster and has a far better performance than a loop with to dump every database in a single file. Why? And how to speed up performance for the looped version

[image]

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases  | gzip > /backup/all_databases.sql.gz
```

and this loop over 65 databases even with nice:

```
nice -n 19 mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf" --databases -c xxx -q > /backup/mysql/xxx_08.sql
nice -n 19 mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf" --databases -c dj-xxx -q > /backup/mysql/dj-xxx_08.sql
nice -n 19 mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf" --databases -c dj-xxx-p -q > /backup/mysql/dj-xxx-p_08.sql
nice -n 19 mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf" --databases -c dj-foo -q > /backup/mysql/dj-foo_08.sql
```

mysqldump.cnf is only used for the authentication, there are no additional options there.

Comment: You're running with very different options, e.g. the -q argument, and whatever is in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf , which might greatly affect the result. Did you try running with the same options ? (also note that running the first dump might pull in much of the data in memory, so when you run the other commands an hour later, it can benefit from that cache)

Comment: mysqldump.cnf is only used for the authentication, there are no additional options.

Comment: And when you dump all the databases with the -q option ? It also seems you are not compressing the sql in your 2. example, so the commands could spend a lot of time writing to the hard drive. (all of this makes a _huge_ difference on my own backups, they might or might not on yours -  i.e.: make the tests as equal as possible so we can eliminate obvious differences.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many differences.

1. In A you are writing to gzip which compresses the data before writing to disk. B writes plain sql files which can be 5-10 times bigger (results from my database). If your performance is disk bound this could be the solution
2. -c = "full inserts" is not specified in A
3. -q is not specified in A
4. for large databases `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` queries can be a pain with mysql (try executing `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns`. For B every dump has to do these queries while A has to do this only once.

Comment: thanks for your answer, not compressing the files was the main performance leak..